# How to make text box editable like of Google docs presentation workspace?

Tags: javascript, google-docs

I am working on on a new project which is to make a presentation maker like of Google docs presentation maker. I was unable to find a way to make the text box selectable and editable like of Google docs presentation workspace:

[image]

Like the one above.
Any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i want to learn and want to do it using pure javascript, not the jquery library. Is there anyplace to learn it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`contentEditable` attribute](http://help.dottoro.com/ljwqtkhj.php) for dom elements.
Here's a live demo (built using jquery) that's using it : http://jsfiddle.net/Z9tVM/;

#### UPDATE :

Here's a demo without using any frameworks (just plain js) : http://jsfiddle.net/Z9tVM/2/

Comment: i want to learn and want to do it using pure javascript, not the jquery library. Is there anyplace to learn it?

Comment: The only thing jQuery was used at in the example was at event binding. The logic that makes the content editable remains the same.

Comment: ok thanx, the part i don't understand is why is it require to use stop propagation method, it is not bubbling up to anything?

Comment: thankyou @gion_13 for this amazing example,i am curious to know the functionality of stopPropagation() and preventDefault() in this example athough i know their functionality. could you please?